# Issue in chunking the file using RamdomAccesFile and FileChannel

Tags: java, file-io, java-7, nio

I wrote this piece of code to chunk the files into multiple chunks. The program works fine for a file of size 12KB with chunk size of 8KB. However, when I give a input file size of 2980144 bytes, it goes into spin - never comes out.

Is there something to do with the size of input file and the FileChannel issue to access? I want to use this program to chunk the larger files (binary form) into multiple chunks for easy transport over network. I have kept the chunk size as parameter, so that I can configure as per requirement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int chunkSize = 8000;

    long offset = 0;
    while (offset >= 0) {
        offset = splitter.GetNextChunk(offset);
    }
}

public long GetNextChunk(long offset) {

    long bytesRead = 0;
    ByteBuffer tmpBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(chunkSize);
    RandomAccessFile outFile = null;
    RandomAccessFile inFile = null;
    FileChannel inFC = null;
    FileChannel outFC = null;

    try {
        inFile = new RandomAccessFile(inFileName, "r");
        inFC = inFile.getChannel();
        tmpBuf.clear();

        // Seek to the offset in the file
        inFC.position(offset);

        // Read the specified number of bytes into the buffer.  
        do {
            bytesRead = inFC.read(tmpBuf);
        } while (bytesRead != -1 && tmpBuf.hasRemaining());

        // Write the copied bytes into a new file (chunk).
        String outFileName = outFolder + File.separator + "Chunk" + String.valueOf(chunkCounter++) + ".dat";
        outFile = new RandomAccessFile(outFileName, "rw");
        outFC = outFile.getChannel();

        outFC.position(0);
        tmpBuf.flip();

        while(tmpBuf.hasRemaining()) {
            outFC.write(tmpBuf);
        }

        // Reposition the buffer to 0.
        tmpBuf.rewind();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (inFC != null)
                inFile.close();

            if (outFC != null)
                outFile.close();

            if (inFC != null)
                inFC.close();

            if (outFC != null)
                outFC.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return bytesRead;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. The loop was faulty. Below is the correct loop.

```
    while (bytesRead >= 0) {
        bytesRead = splitter.GetNextChunk(offset);

        if (bytesRead == -1)
            break;

        offset += bytesRead;
        System.out.println("Byte offset is: " + offset);
    }
```

Comment: I just found that and wanted to ask you of what the return value means.

Answer (score 1):

It's not nearly as hard as you're making it. Your code is about ten times as long as it needs to be. Try this:

```
while (in.read(buffer) > 0 || buffer.position() > 0)
{
    buffer.flip();
    out.write(buffer);
    buffer.compact();
}
```

If 'out' is a SocketChannel this will send the file over the network at maximum speed.

You don't need a monstro buffer, but you should always use powers of 2. I generally use 8192.

Comment: Agreed, however I need to wrap this chunks with another layer of information before they are sent over to the network.